# dimension of vector space of functions from {0} to real number set.

Tags: vector-spaces

Let V be a vector space of all functions from {0} $\rightarrow R$. Then the dimension of the vector space $V$.

What I have done is $V=${$f_r /  f_r:${0}$\rightarrow R , f_r(0)=r$} is the given vector space.
Basis of V is {$f_r(0)=r$} for any r $\neq 0$.
So the dimension is 1.

Comment: Looks good. Where is the question?

Comment: I am asking whether it is right or not

Comment: it looks good. If it is homework, you might want to add some details, like why does $\{ f_{r} \}$ for $r\ne 0$ span the whole space and why it is minimal (well the empty set only spans the null space).